# How to select ids that a user has not viewed

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

In my notification current the day I used a `view` column in update table which update `view = 1` if viewed else `view = 0` . But in case for make notification for many user for a particular update, its cannot work if a user viewed first.

So I create that new table named updateview to stored post_id & user_id that viewed. (here `post_id` is update table's `id`)

My update table where all update stored and a updateview table which stored update table id and user ID if user viewed any update. That means updateview table insert id & userID when user view any post from notification drop-down menu.

How how to create SELECT Statement for select all update table **`id`** that was not in updateview **`post_id`**.

Here is my update table: [no foreign key, `id(AI)`]

```
id | work_id | from_id | to_id | date
```

updateview table: [no foreign key, id(AI)]

```
id | post_id | user_id
```

Here below my 3rd query select all id from update table that related with user follower, fan page. Here I want reduce that id which find in updateview table.

Query 1: Get all follower id and return: `$f2_ids[] = $row['follow'];`

Query 2: Get all liked fan page id and return : `$pg_ids[] = $row['userid'];`

Query 3:

```
foreach((array)$f2_ids as $indx => $value) {

$myid = $session->id;

    $g = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT id FROM update WHERE 
        `to_id`='".$myid."' AND `from_id`='".$f2_ids[$indx]."' OR
        `to_id`='".$f2_ids[$indx]."' AND `from_id`='".$myid."' OR
        `to_id`='".$pg_ids[$indx]."' OR 
        `from_id`='".$pg_ids[$indx]."' AND `to_id`='0' GROUP BY id") or
        die(mysqli_error($db));
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($g); 
    //etc... do something....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) Function

```
$count = count($g);
```